# Make a To Do/Task Manager iOS App with UITableView, EditMode, and plist file?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have to make an app for a camp that I'm attending. I want to make a task manager/to do list app. I want to have a tableview with the tasks. When you tap on a task, it will show a new page with the details of the task. You can add a new task with a description in two different text fields (one for each.) I want the entries to be saved to a plist file that would be read by the table view. I need a way to start edit mode to rearrange and delete the items from the TableView and the plist. When you touch the add button, I want a screen to come up with a UITextField and a UITextView. The text field would be for the task name and the text view for the details. Does anyone know any tutorials or code that could get me started? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you storing the tasks in a p-list rather than in Core Data?

Answer (score 0):

You should check out this tutorial.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/21842/how-to-make-a-gesture-driven-to-do-list-app-part-13

It runs through how to make a persistent to-do list and will help you get your start.